# attempt to index a nil value (local 'result') error

Tags: lua, fivem

i'm not a coder, but i'm trying to learn how to make a fivem server, and I keep getting an error that says

> @es_extended/server/main.lua:93: attempt to index a nil value (local 'result')

i'm trying to solve this error but it's being hard.
here is my code

```
function loadESXPlayer(identifier, playerId)
local tasks = {}

local userData = {
    accounts = {},
    inventory = {},
    job = {},
    loadout = {},
    playerName = GetPlayerName(playerId),
    weight = 0
}

table.insert(tasks, function(cb)
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll('SELECT accounts, job, job_grade, `group`, loadout, position, inventory FROM users WHERE identifier = @identifier', {
        ['@identifier'] = identifier
    }, function(result)
        local job, grade, jobObject, gradeObject = result[1].job, tostring(result[1].job_grade)
        local foundAccounts, foundItems = {}, {}
```

This is the line that has some kind of error:

```
local job, grade, jobObject, gradeObject = result[1].job, tostring(result[1].job_grade)
```

please help!

Comment: `\`group\`` seems a bit odd, why does it have \`s around it? try narrowing your sql query, just guessing but i think you might be getting an error while running the query and that is why `result` is `nil` in the function, not finding much in the documentation to support that theory though

Comment: `group` is a SQL reserved word, so it would be wise to quote it.

Comment: Also, the assignment `local job, grade, jobObject, gradeObject = result[1].job, tostring(result[1].job_grade)` has three variables in the left part but only two expressions in the right.

Comment: Wrap the insides of `function(result)` in `if result then ... end`, so that when the result is `nil`, there would be no run-time error. Why `result` is `nil`, I don't know: it may be because there is no user with given identifier, or there is some error in the querym or misconfigured connection to the daabase.